# format report in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to dispaly only the total when level3 and level1 are blank?
Here is a screen shot of the report:
[image]

I have a second question: when I export the report to pdf, it doesn't dispaly all row and columns, how to correct it?

Here is the file pbix https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vJ0DkosStnfCE5FiS3RQDO4h1TPV8Mm7/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Power BI export functionalities are extremely basic and limited. The application is not intended to export the data. Instead, you publish it on Power BI Service and all users access it through the browser.

What I might suggest you is to explore some third-party tools trying to customize extractions, for example [this](https://go.christiansteven.com/power-bi-reports-scheduler-ssrs-reports-distribution-pbrs) gives you a free trial. You can investigate whether it helps in solving this specific Use Case.

Otherwise, my personal suggestion is to address the business need in a different way.

Comment: have you any idea about my first question displaying only total please?

Comment: In the pane where you add attribute to the visualization, try to right click on the attribute SHOW ITEM WITH NO DATA. This option should be deselected.

Comment: Then last try thing I would try is filter the measure to not be blank. However it might impact performance.

Comment: How to do it please?

Comment: Select visual and apply a filter on the measure using the filter panel on the right